# Karma not returning control to the prompt after running all tests

Tags: tdd, bdd, karma-runner

I am having a weird issue with Karma. It's my first time using it and it seems to be working fine; I can see in the prompt that every test has been executed without errors, but, for some reason, the prompt is frozen there and not coming back.

Any hint anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: In your `karma.conf.js` do you have the `singleRun` property set to `false`? In case, change it to `true`.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but I'd already tried it. Any idea more?

Comment: I think we may need some more details then. can you post the karma configuration? Browsers used? Are you using/hacking any karma hook?